# Maximizing a functional with respect to a function

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

I want to find the function $u(r)$ maximizing the functional $F(u(r))$:

$$F(u(r))=\int_{-R}^{R} u(r)^2 dr$$

subject to the constraints below:

$$\int_{-R}^{R}u(r) dr= U_0 $$
$$u(-R)=u(R)=0$$
in which $U_o$ is a constant.

Update: $u(r)$ is twice differentiable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The supremum of the functional $F(u)$ is $+\infty$.
Consider the sequence of functions defined by
$$
u_n(x)=U_0 n/R\quad \textrm{if } -R/(2n)\le x\le R/(2n),\quad u_n(x)=0 \textrm{ elsewhere}
$$
The functions satisfy the constraints, but
$$
\int_{-R}^R u_n(x)^2 dx=nU_0^2/R
$$
tending to infinity. 
The answer dos not change if we add the hypothesis that $u$ is differentiable (even infinite times). One can just substitute $u_n$ with a smoothed version of the "peak function"

Comment: thanks, I should have mentioned that u(r) is twice differentiable. I add it as an update to the question.

Comment: Ok, but the the conclusion is the same. I update the answer too

Comment: You are right. The only thing missing is a division by $R$ in the definition of $u_n(x)$

Comment: ah yes! I correct it.